# How should I describe my country's volatile situation in a letter for a scholarship application?

Tags: application, funding

I'm writing a letter of motivation to apply for a master degree scholarship. However, my marks in final years of study weren't the highest possible due to the effect of the ongoing crisis in my country, Syria, on me.

In [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18234/mentioning-my-country-situation-in-motivation-letter-to-demonstrate-dedication-f), I asked whether I should mention this in my letter, and the answer was that I should.

Now I want to know, what is the *best way* to mention this in my letter? Is one paragraph about it too much?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something along the lines that you persisted and managed to graduate despite that the life as you know it was being destroyed in a war-torn county. The hardships of war, hunger, constant fear for safety (or whatever you feel like sharing) gave priority to the survival. As the result your grades in the final years suffered. You are eager to continue your education in the safety of whereever you are applying, and ready to give it your all without the distractions of the war.

The point you want to make is that you graduated during the whole crisis, which is truly impressive. Congratulations on that. It shows the character and persistence. Grades you can fix.